# Conditional Probability SAS

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, probability

I am trying to contact either the user "**Billy Bob**" or the user "**user:6832830**" regarding a post on conditional probability tables in SAS.  I wanted to comment but don't have enough rep to do that.

The OP can be found here [Conditional Probability Table in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500028/conditional-probability-table-in-sas)

I am running into the same problem with memory in trying to use the solution.  I was wondering if anyone figured out how to use the solution on a large datasets (mine is 89 columns and 500K rows).  The rest of the code runs fine, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Spanman

Comment: Making the OBS array temporary might help.  array obs[&NOBS,&NCOLS] _ temporary _;

Comment: Note that you can edit your original post. I don't think you need reputation to  edit own posts.